# Do team-bonding exercises promote distrust?

Tags: sociology, work

In [*Barking Up the Wrong Tree*](http://amzn.to/2Esance), author Eric Barker makes the claim:

> You can't rely on HR team-bonding exercises; studies show they're only effective at building distrust.
>
> -- *Chapter 4*

There is no citation, and my attempts to find relevant studies on Google have only resulted in similarly unsourced claims, but usually in praise of team-building exercises.

Are there actually studies that show that HR-style "team-bonding" exercises promote distrust?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are studies showing the contrary

[This meta analysis](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0169604) shows

> the overall take-home message is that teamwork training is an effective way to foster teamwork and team performance

[and this study](http://www.iaeme.com/MasterAdmin/uploadfolder/IJMHRM_06_03_010/IJMHRM_06_03_010.pdf) shows

> These findings seem to
>   suggest that Team Building Exercises do have an impact on the scores of the all Six
>   TAQ Sub Scales. In other words, there is an association between attending team
>   building exercises and team effectiveness
>
> Looking at the observed values, it may also be
>   suggested that Team Building Intervention is successful in increasing Team
>   Effectiveness.

Comment: Are these studies specifically "HR-style" exercises, or all of them?

Comment: The articles talk about "Team training" or "Team building" in general, you will need to dig deeper into the quoted articles to get the context, I do agree that there might be a difference between a team building exercise and HR team building exercise, the latter being shorter and more sporadic